# How do I hit the equivalent of `C-u` (of normal emacs) in Spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs

According to the "Evilified modes" documentation [1], `C-u` gets moved to `C-U`, but when I try to hit that (Ctrl+Shift+u), my cursor still gets moved one page up, instead of starting a new long command.

[1] - http://spacemacs.org/doc/DOCUMENTATION.html#evilified-modes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That would be `SPC u` if memory serves me correctly.

Comment: Any idea if there is a way to call the C-u prefix in insert mode?

Comment: @user1338062 If you use `dotspacemacs-editing-style 'hybrid`, you can `C-u M-x your-command` as you normally would. `hybrid` generally makes insert mode work like normal Emacs.

Answer (score 2):

Read [Universal argument](https://www.spacemacs.org/doc/DOCUMENTATION.html#universal-argument) in the documentation:

> Spacemacs binds `C-u` to `scroll-up` and change the universal argument binding to `SPC u`.

In insert mode, space will obviously insert space, so `C-u` needs to be typed after the command, before `RET`:

> **Note**: `SPC u` is not working before `helm-M-x` (`SPC SPC`). Instead, call `helm-M-x` first, select the command you want to run, and press `C-u` before pressing `RETURN`. For instance: `SPC SPC org-reload C-u RET`