# How do I use keys bound to a command with universal argument in Spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs

In spacemacs, a lot of commands have bound keys such as `leader x a`. For those commands that accept universal argument, how can I pass them to these command with key bindings? `leader space leader x a` does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this question is the same as the one posed here: [How do I hit the equivalent of `C-u` (of normal emacs) in Spacemacs?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/44841/how-do-i-hit-the-equivalent-of-c-u-of-normal-emacs-in-spacemacs/44842#44842)

Anyway: use `SPC u` (or `leader u`) and then the keystrokes for the command you want to use a prefix with.